# Find a formula for the transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to solve this problem. No luck...

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on vector space $V$ over field $F$.
>
> $$\begin{align}
> V & = \Bbb C^4\\
> F & = \Bbb C
> \end{align}$$
>
> Find a formula for $T$ such that $T^2 = 0$,
>
> $$N(T) = \text{span}\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\}$$
>
> and $\text{rank}(T) = 2$

I'm familiar with $T^2 = 0$ if and only if $R(T) \subseteq N(T)$ but still can't figure it out.

Comment: If you are using specific $F$ and $V$, why suggest the are general first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the two given vectors of $N(T)$ (which I suppose means $\ker(T)$) to a basis of$~V$. Those two vectors must map to$~0$, and images of the other two will spann $R(T)$. Since the rank must be $2$ and $T^2=0$, it must be that $R(T)=N(T)$. Now after choosing those two images, you have fixed $T$ on a complete basis of$~V$, so determined $T$. Since it is common to describe linear operators on $\Bbb C^n$ on with respect to the *standard* basis, you might finally want to compute the values $T(e_i)$ for $e_i$ in the standard basis.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Still a bit confused about how to find T. Okay So N(T) = R(T) = span{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)}?  This means T(1,1,0,0)=T(0,0,1,0) = (0,0,0,0) How do i choose the images of R(T)? From what I understand about R(T) is that if R(T) = span{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)} then some T(P) and T(Q) = (1,1,0,0) and (0,0,1,0) respectively. How do I proceed from here to find T?

Comment: It's true that R(T) = span{T(e1),T(e2),T(e3),T(e4)} ?

Comment: As my answer says, begin with completing the given two vectors to a basis; the extra two vectors can be your $P,Q$. There are many ways to choose them, but choosing them _among_ the standard basis is always possible, and simplifies the rest. And (second comment) yes that should always be true.

Comment: Marc :) I have solved the problem. I particularly appreciate that you did not solve it for me, your guidelines have helped me gain greater understanding of the content.